# How much user is scrolling up beyond scrollTop zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What I am trying to accomplish is when the user has scrolled to the top of the window / body, but attempts to scroll up further, then as per the distance the user scrolls up, this element ( `#main` ) is dragged down. It is currently made draggable through jQueryUI.

How I planned to drag it down is by simulating the `.mousedown()` and and `.mousemove()` and `.mouseup() events, which seem to work ( meaning they trigger the drag ).

Here is what I think should work in some-real / some-pseudo code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0){

        if(extra movement beyond scrollTop 0){
             $('#main').mousedown();
             //move #main down number of pixels of extra movement / extra scroll up.
             $('#main').mouseup();   
        }
    } 
});
```

So I want to learn how much the user is scrolling up or attempting to scroll up beyond the top of the page and the move an element that number of pixels by calling mouse down and then moving the mouse on that element that number of pixels down, which should trigger the jQuery UI drag for that amount of pixels down.

Comment: By attempting to simulate `mouse` events you're making it harder. Why not just update the position of the `#main` element using jQuery CSS method.

Comment: As soon as the Top/Bottom is reached, you may store the Y-Pos of the mouse and then listen on mousemove events, track the Y, calculate the diff from the stored Y pos and move the #main div. Hard to tell when to stop doing so, there needs to be an event which the stops moving around #main.

Comment: @AxelAmthor Can you write an answer showing how to do that? I have another script that will refresh the page once `#main` has been dragged down 161 pixels.